# Update document doesnt work right

Tags: php, arrays, mongodb

I am using the code below to update a MongoDB document:

```
foreach($jArray as $value){ 
            $tablename = $value['tablename'];
            $ean = $value["ean"];
            $amount= $value["amount"];
            $new_data = array(
                '$set' => array(
                'inventar' => array(
                array (
                'ean' => $ean,
                'amount' => $amount
                )
                )
                )
            );          
            $collection->update(array("tablename"=>$tablename), $new_data);
            $response["update"] = 1;
            echo json_encode($response);
        }
```

The database looks like executing the code like this:

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$id": "557daa73d8291bc6268b4578"
    },
    "inventar": [
        {
            "ean": "802.6180.222",
            "amount": "0"
        }
    ],
    "out_date": "15.05.2015",
    "out_email": "email@email.com",
    "out_user": "pb",
    "tablename": "DD_AA"
}
```

but the inventar-part should be contain more values.

the json I send is:

```
[{"amount":"0","ean":"802.0079.127","tablename":"DD_AA"},{"amount":"40","ean":"802.6180.222","tablename":"DD_AA"}]
```

**Why the second ean is forgotten and not updated?
Is the structure right?**

Thank you

Comment: is your loop working perfectly?

Comment: at least the 2 tablenames are given if I echo it

Comment: do you want to add new item to the array specified by tablename?

Comment: exactly, instead of id I need the tablename

Comment: `update(array("tablename"=>$tablename),array('$push' => array("inventar" => $new_data)));`
try like this... i think, it'll work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why the second ean is forgotten [...] ?

As suggested by @gypsyCoder in a comment, using `$push` will solve your issue.

The reason is that [`$set`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/set/) will create or *replace* a field. But, [`$push`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/push/) create an array field if it does not already exists, and append the item at the end of that array.

So, given you example, the correct code should look like this:

```
        $new_data = array(
            '$push' => array(
                'inventar' => array(
                    'ean' => $ean,
                    'amount' => $amount
                )
            )
        );  

        $collection->update(array("tablename"=>$tablename), $new_data);
```

Please note, by default `$push` will only push one item at a time. So, you must not wrap the item to push in an array. If you need to push several items as part of the same update statement, you need to wrap all the elements in an array, passed as an argument to the [`$each`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/each/#up._S_each) modifier.

Comment: $new_data = array(
    array (
    'ean' => $ean,
    'amount' => $amount
    )
   );   and $collection->update(array("tablename"=>$tablename),array('$push' => array("inventar" => $new_data)));